# AS3: How to show Hindi number in Input and Dynamic text?

Tags: actionscript-3, text, unicode, utf, hindi

I have a project where I  calculate the **Area of a triangle**.

**Problem:**
The problem is the number appear as Arabic and I want it to be shown as a Hindi (Devanagari) font's number?

**What I tried:** 
I have try more fonts same problem.

Comment: So, please show us what have you tried so far and what kind of **algorithmic** problem makes it difficult for you to convert arabic numbers to hindi?

Comment: Do you have a font that has Hindi numbers? Did you embed it in the IDE or by code (meaning can you use it)? Anyways check the `yourString.charCodeAt(0)` for a number like `3` when it is Arabic and for when it is Hindi (if the charCode numbers are different then maybe you need an IF statement to change from Arabic to the equivalent Hindi number).

Comment: Since you don't care to respond to people trying to help you, my final suggestion is that you test: `var yourString : String = String.fromCharCode(2409);` now does `yourString` look like **३**? If not then you need to use **Arial Unicode** font or some **Devanagari** font (I don't know what _"I have try more font"_ even means. It doesn't tell us what font NAME you tried). Make sure you **embed** the font. Embedding will depend on whether you are doing it by AS3 code or by options in your IDE. Nobody knows anything about how you set the fonts. Google search will respond if you ask. Good luck.